# Graphic novel: Soldier woven in barbed wire with something like angels' wings

Tags: story-identification, comics

I have read this graphic novel between 2000 and 2005 in the library. It was an around Din A4 sized hardcover book, but thin. Maybe original France, but I read it in German language. The title could be something with uppercase letter "X".

The title or one of the first pictures showed a soldier in World War (WW2 I assume, but maybe WW1). I assume he was dead, hanging in barbed wire. There was the impression of angels wings in this picture. I do not remember, if the barbed wire fored this shape, or if it was a shadow-like second picture "behind" the first picture.

The story was something dark, with god and angels. So I hope I meet the Scifi.SE criteria. It was a bigger timeframe than only World War. The different times were woven with each other. It leaves the impression of a reasoning that there must be angels, so the described picture could be some kind of "proof" in the whole story. I could remember no "action", the whole feeling was "sadness".

I remember how impressed I was from the pictures. They were like pencil drawings. Not so clean like this ones which are made with a computer's help. I cannot remember some colors, so I assume it was almost in black and white, maybe some sepia or brown on the title.

I wish to see these pictures​ again, to explore my long-lasting impression of it.

Comment: WW2, angels and soldiers make me think of the graphic novel *The Light Brigade" by Peter Tomasi and Peter Snejbjerg. I don't, however recall any prominent use of barbed wire. https://www.amazon.com/Light-Brigade-Peter-J-Tomasi/dp/1401207952

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen I assume "DC Comics" I would remember. And the impression is "to much color" but Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find the specific image you're looking for, but I have a pretty good feeling you're remembering the French series *XXe ciel.com* (1997-2001) by Yslaire.

Translated from [Babelio](https://www.babelio.com/livres/Yslaire-XXe-cielcom-Tome-1--Memoires-98/9487):

> Brussels, Marche 1st, 1998. Eva Stern lets herself be carried away by a strange dream. She dreams of an angel with a wounded forehead, looking down from the clouds over a World War I battlefield. Soldiers are agonizing at his feet. Among them is Eva's brother Frank, with a camera in his hand, who finds the strength to capture his last photography.
>
> The next day, Eva is puzzled by an e-mail sent by a mysterious "@nonymous". **A succession of photos retracing the twentieth century. All of them depict beings with arms outstretched, like angels.** Eva, a psychoanalyst born with the century and preparing to die with it, seeks to understand. Her quest begins, which will revive the memory of Frank, the missing brother whose last photo bore the strange words "ich bin ewig" - I am eternal...

From what I gather around, I *think* this does fit in the science-fiction/fantasy category, in a weird "dreamlike" kind of way. The images I can fetch from Google images match your recollection of pencil-drawn gloom with little to no colors, and I can imagine them leaving an impression:

[image: gloomy picture of two men with a syringe]

[image: covers of various albums in the series]

---

Found with the Google query `bande dessinee science fiction anges dieu guerre mondiale` (`science fiction comic angels god world war`), which returned the Babelio link above.

Comment: Translated in German as [*Der XX. Himmel*](https://www.zvab.com/buch-suchen/titel/der-xx-himmel/autor/yslaire/).

Comment: Perfect Match! Like a christmas present :D The one I read was the first of the four books in you picture. I do not know it is a series. I looking forward to read the others!